# In how many ways can $6$ of different types be worn on $3$ fingers?

Tags: combinatorics

"Find out the number of ways in which $6$ rings of different types can be worn in $3$ fingers?"

My answer is $6C3 = 20$ ways. However, there is no choice for my answer and I supposed it is incorrect. But, with the change in the solution, $3^6 = 729$ - which is provided in the choices, and thus, valid answer for this problem.

I don't wanna resort to hunch and for that I just want to have an explanation for this one.

Comment: It depends on how many fingers there are in total.

Answer (score 1):

If the rings are distinguishable, then I assume that the order in which they're placed on a finger matters. Start by placing rings on finger 1; then place rings on finger 2; then place rings on finger 3. There are eight actions (place ring 1, ..., place ring 6, move to next finger, move to next finger) which can be in any order, so how many sequences are possible, taking into account that two of them are equal?

If the rings are not distinguishable, there are still eight actions but six of them are "place a ring" and two of them are "move to next finger", so how many sequences are possible?

In the extremely unlikely case that the fingers are also indistinguishable,  we're looking at partitions of 6 into at most 3 parts.